# Y axe always visible

Tags: iphone, core-plot

I'm drawing a graph like behind using core-plot. I wanted to put de Y axe out of the "plotAreaFrame", like that I'll be able to see it all the time, even when I'm scrolling on the X axe.

If it's not possible could you give me a clue to make the Y Axe always visible.

[image]

Edit: May I do this by drawing an other chart an displaying only the axes of the second graph and no datas on it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
y.isFloatingAxis = YES;
```

That was just that line!

Answer (score 2):

In the newest version of Core Plot, isFloatingAxis no longer works, but this does:

```
y.axisConstraints = [CPTConstraints constraintWithLowerOffset:0];
```